# How to construct a matrix for vector-mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a (probably trivial) mathematical issue which I just can’t wrap my head around. Disclaimer: I’m an engineer, not a mathematician so please excuse any mistakes along the road and my Matlab notation...

My challenge is to map the values inside vector **a** of length *m* into vector **b** of length *n*.

A pen-and-paper example with `m = 4` and `n = 3` of this would look like that:

`a = [6 6 6 6]` should map to `b = [8 8 8]` so that the sum of all elements remains constant in both vectors;

To achieve this mapping, I construct a matrix (by hand) **T** with `T = 1/3 * [3 0 0; 1 2 0; 0 2 1; 0 0 3]` so that `b = a * T`.

My question is, how can I construct this matrix for arbitrary and larger values for *m* and *n*? I am not afraid to google, but it seems I don’t have the right vocabulary for a successful search.

Any help or link is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I assume that the elements in vector $\mathbf{a}$ are not always the same like in your example, right? If so, then there are not enough specifications in order to solve the problem (uniquely). One more thing, is $m>n$ always satisfied?

Comment: Yes, the values in **a** are undefined. And yes, _m > n_ is satisfied.

Comment: But how would you then transform a vector like $[1, 2, 3]$ for $n=2$? It could be $[3, 3]$, $[1, 5]$, etc. What kind of extra constraints on the solution do you have?

Comment: I try to evenly distribute the values in **a** into **b**.
My manual approach for [1,2,3] and _n = 2_ would be as follows:

1) divide the values of **a** into m*n cells: [1,2,3] then becomes [0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.5]

2) take the sum of pairs of _m_: [0.5+0.5+1.0,1.0+1.5+1.5] = [2,4]